# How remove line connecting the beginning and the end in a Scatter in plotly?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, plotly

When I create plotly scatter in this way:

```
trace_high = go.Scatter(x=data_df['timestamp'], y=data_fr['high'], name= 'high price')
trace_low = go.Scatter(x=data_df['timestamp'], y=data_fr['low'], name='low price')

data = [trace_high, trace_low]

layout = go.Layout(title=dict(text = 'price'),
                              xaxis = dict(rangeslider=dict(),
                                           type='date'))

fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)

fig.show()
```

I recive plot like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ffwc.png)

How remove the line connecting the beginning and the end of data? Why is it being created?

Comment: I was looking similar question but I didn't find any. It's looks like post you linked it doesn't help me alot. :/

Comment: I found solutions. It was problem in my data. I think you can close the post. 
Sorry. :)